# Vim delimitmate append blank line after closing bracket

Tags: text, vim, delimiter

I have installed delimitmate to auto-close parantheses/brackets.
I had to do this remapping in my .vimrc file: `inoremap { {<CR>}<up><end><CR>`.
I am required to also append a blank/new line AFTER the closing bracket like so:

Expected:

```
public int get() {
    //code
}
*append new line after typing '{'
@Override
public String toString() {
   //code
}
```

Current: No newline added after auto-closing bracket

```
    public int get() {
        //code
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
       //code
    }
```

Would appreciate any help in remapping the key to add a newline after the closing bracket.

Comment: Why do you have that mapping if you have that plugin?

Comment: it does not insert a newline even inside the brackets when i type {

Comment: You should probably read the plugin's documentation more carefully.

Comment: Type `{<cr>` instead.

Comment: Beside, the extra newline after the closing bracket would mess control statements. I doubt you want `if (...) {\ncode\n}\n\nelse..`

Comment: @LucHermitte Tried this, it does not append a newline after the }, is there a key binding for newline like \n for vim?

Comment: @LucHermitte true, but they want a newline in between methods

Comment: `{<cr>` should expand into `{\n<indented-cursor>\n}` with nearly almost all auto-pairing plugins.  Regarding the newline after the method definition, I'm afraid it'll require some more assistance. May be the mapping could try detect to detect whether the `{` isn't on a newline, nor after a control-statement keyword, nor after a `=` (and may be other possible cases that would make sense in what? Java?). I don't know whether the plugin you've chosen permits contextual analysis before expansion. My lh-brackets plugin does permit it, but some extra work will be required.